# Node_exporter node_systemd_unit_state

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to monitor particular services via node_exporter, without the need to point them in node_exporter service with  `--collector.systemd.unit-include="(foo|bar)\\.service"`

How this should be defined in prometheus config ?

I was trying

```
- name: Services monitoring
rules:
- alert: Service is down
 expr: node_systemd_unit_state{name="ubrokerd|besclient|boksm|collectd|crond|ldapauth|network|NetworkManager|sshd|tomcat|ubrokerd|nginx|node_exporter\\.service", state="inactive"} == 1
 for: 0m
 labels:
   severity: warning
 annotations:
   summary: service is down on host {{ $labels.instance }}
   description: "Service is down"
```

but this not seems to work - alert is not firing if any of the services go down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your `expr`:

1. You use literal match operator (`=`) instead of regex match (`=~`).
2. You need to put the list inside parentheses, otherwise `\\.service` applies only to the last item.

Try this:

```yaml
 expr: node_systemd_unit_state{name=~"(ubrokerd|besclient|boksm|collectd|crond|ldapauth|network|NetworkManager|sshd|tomcat|ubrokerd|nginx|node_exporter)\\.service", state="inactive"} == 1
```